# trigram index isn't used

Tags: postgresql

I've [created](https://github.com/ypapax/limit_not_using_postgres_trigram_index/blob/master/init.sql#L12) a trigram index:

```
CREATE DATABASE people;

\connect people;
CREATE TABLE people
(
    id        bigserial NOT NULL,
    name      text      NULL
);

CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX name_trigram_idx ON people USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

But it's not used:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5439 -U postgres -d people -c 'EXPLAIN (ANALYZE true, FORMAT TEXT) SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ILIKE '\''%juxtapositions%'\'''
                          Gather  (cost=1000.00..270871.24 rows=1695 width=87) (actual time=15727.803..15730.149 rows=1 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..269701.74 rows=706 width=87) (actual time=10508.202..15714.003 rows=0 loops=3)
         Filter: (name ~~* '%wisest juxtapositions%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 5650000
 Planning Time: 17.167 ms
 Execution Time: 15730.344 ms
```

What could be a reason for it?

## Update

postgres version:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5439 -U postgres -d people -c 'SELECT version()'
                                                             version                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Query with `set enable_seqscan=off` and `ANALYZE, BUFFERS`:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5439 -U postgres -d people -c 'set enable_seqscan=off; EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ILIKE '\''%wisest juxtapositions%'\'''
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on people  (cost=1666.59..4820.04 rows=850 width=55) (actual time=49.955..49.961 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (name ~~* '%wisest juxtapositions%'::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=3693
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on name_trigram_idx  (cost=0.00..1666.38 rows=850 width=0) (actual time=49.937..49.944 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (name ~~* '%wisest juxtapositions%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=3693
 Planning Time: 1.083 ms
 Execution Time: 50.160 ms
(8 rows)
```

## Update 2

pg_trgm version is `1.4`:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5439 -U postgres -d people -c '\dx'
                                       List of installed extensions
     Name      | Version |   Schema   |                            Description                            
---------------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 fuzzystrmatch | 1.1     | public     | determine similarities and distance between strings
 pg_trgm       | 1.4     | public     | text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams
 plpgsql       | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
```

Comment: thanx `set enable_seqscan=off` helped to force using the index and it is actually slower while using index. But how is it possible that the index is useless in this case

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the case with seqscan disabled.  What version are you using, both of PostgreSQL and of pg_trgm?

Comment: added explain with seqscan disabled above and postgres version, not sure how to get pg_trgm version

Comment: This is confusing, as it looks like it certainly should be using the index.  The index cost estimate is 4820, the seq scan cost estimate is 270871, 50 times more expensive.  Perhaps a vacuum or analyze had kicked in between those runs, or the data changed substantially?  Can you alternate between seq scan on and off several times in quick succession to make sure you have stable results?  You can get the extension versions with \dx in psql.